# Application close when click home button - Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have written a Xamarin forms application which is run on both iOS and Android platforms. In iOS when i click "Home" button Application is closing instead of going back ground. When i open the application again it will start from the beginning. It doesn't open the application from where i left.

Normally in iOS applications, when we click home button it will save the application state and goes to back ground. When we open the application again, it will open the last screen where we left. As per my knowledge, Normally we don't need to handle this in native iOS application which is developed by Xcode.

I didn't change any codes in App.xaml or AppDelegate. Kindly hope advice on this to solve this issue.

Comment: hey check this thread https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100898/home-button-destroys-app'

Comment: Have you debug it in a simulator or a real device to check if there is any error?